# Чтение определенного столбца в .csv файле

Tags: c#

В .csv файле имеется 4 колонки, необходимо считать информацию только из первой колонки. Пока вижу решение только через регулярные выражения.

Подскажите, может быть есть более простой способ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если разбивать строку запятыми и сохранять только первый столбец:

```
List<string> parsed = new List<string>();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("...")) {
    string row;

    while ((row = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
        parsed.Add(row.Split(',')[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Как минимум два решения:

1. Читать все до запятой и переходить на следующую строку
2. Читать строку, через split (в зависимости от языка), создавать массив и выдирать только первый элемент